# executing spring roo without using internet

Tags: spring-roo

Is it possible to generate a project using ROO without using internet to download the plugins automatically.Is there any way to download the plugins manually and put it in the lib folder or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring-roo uses maven to download the plugins. If you do not have internet access you can setup your own repository on your intranet with apache Archiva ( http://archiva.apache.org/) where you can upload the artifacts. Then you can use this repository instead of the internet repositories.

Comment: as you said i have installed apache archiva using archiva.bat install.But when i start it using archiva.bat start but it showing message like "the apache archiva was launched but failed to start". How can i resolve this